# How to port LTRIM from Oracle to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Moving an application from Oracle to SQL Server, I have this pseudo Oracle PL/SQL:

```
SELECT LTRIM(MyColumn, '-, ') FROM MyTable
```

I.e. I'm using [Oracle's `LTRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2018.htm#OLADM594) with a second argument, specifying the characters to trim from the left side of the string.

Unfortunately, the [T-SQL version of `LTRIM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) doesn't allow me to specify the characters to trim.

Currently, I'm rather clueless how to migrate that `LTRIM`. I'm even thinking about processing the results in my hosting C# application, after I read the `MyColumn`.

This looks rather inelegant to me.

**My question:**

Is there any meaningful way of getting an `LTRIM`-like functionality for T-SQL to pass the characters to trim away?

**Edit 1:**

I need to replace `-`, `,` and  from the beginning of the string.

E.g.:

```js
   -----, ,,, This is ,- a test,---,
```

would result in

```js
This is ,- a test,---,
```

**Edit 2:**

I strongly hope this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Maybe rewriting my whole query would remove the need for `LTRIM` altogether, although I would rather focus on porting it as 1:1 as possible and later question the usefulness of the `LTRIM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the suffix of the string starting from the first character which is not a space, comma or hyphen:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '   -----, ,,, This is ,- a test,---,'

select  substring(@str,patindex('%[^ ,-]%',@str),len(@str))
```

Result:

```
This is ,- a test,---,
```

Please note that the hyphen, since it is a special character in regular expressions meaning 'range' (e.g. `[a-z]`), must be either first (`[^- ,]`) or last (`[^ ,-]`).

Comment: Can't you just escape the dash with \ to place it anywhere?

Comment: @majdarif - no, you can't

Answer (score 6):

Yeehaw.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( MyColumn VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT @MyTable ( MyColumn )
    VALUES ( '-----, ,,, This is ,- a test,---,' );

SELECT *, 
        SUBSTRING(mt.MyColumn, ca.p, LEN(mt.MyColumn))
FROM @MyTable AS mt
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT * 
              FROM (VALUES (PATINDEX ('%[^ ,-]%', MyColumn))
            ) AS x (p) ) AS ca;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll be happy with this solution compared to Oracle's `ltrim` but it does what you want.

```
declare @Pattern varchar(32) = '-, ';

select case when MyColumn like '['+@Pattern+']%'
         then right(MyColumn
          , len(MyColumn)-(patindex('%[^'+@Pattern+']%',MyColumn)-1)
          )
       else MyColumn
       end
from MyTable
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/IXOL62563

Answer (score 3):

Can't say if this is the best solution, but this can be accomplished with `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT`, `LTRIM`, and `REPLACE`. I'm assuming that you're working with 8000 or less characters.

Test code:

```
DECLARE @test_string VARCHAR(100) = '   -----, ,,, This is ,- a test,---,';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@test_string, CHARINDEX(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', '')), 1), @test_string + 'Z'), 8000);
```

Output:

> > This is ,- a test,---,

Below is an explanation of each part. I added a "Z" to the end to handle the case in which the string only has the characters that need to be removed. First remove all commas:

```
REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', '')
```

Remove all -:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', '')
```

Remove padded spaces from the left:

```
LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', ''))
```

Grab the first character that isn't space, comma, or -:

```
LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', '')), 1)
```

Find the position of the first character that isn't space, comma, or -:

```
CHARINDEX(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', '')), 1), @test_string + 'Z')
```

Take the substring starting at the position that we found:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@test_string, CHARINDEX(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test_string + 'Z', ',', ''), '-', '')), 1), @test_string + 'Z'), 8000);
```

Comment: Will this work if the string has no other characters but commas, spaces and dashes?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Nope, thanks for the catch. Fixed the code to handle that case.